# Pandas dataframe grouped operation inside numpy function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame consisting of thousands of stock quotes, ordered by symbol(tic) and Date.

```
    Date    tic    prccd
0   1-1-20  AAPL    4.00
1   2-1-20  AAPL    4.10
2   3-1-20  AAPL    4.12
3   1-1-20  MSFT    6.00
4   2-1-20  MSFT    6.15
5   3-1-20  MSFT    6.10
```

With

```
stocks_data['log_return'] = np.log(1 + stocks_data.groupby('tic')['prccd'].pct_change())
```

I aim to get the logarithmic daily return of these stocks. Does the numpy function acknowledge the groupby tic operation?

Comment: numpy dose not know the groupby.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate daily log returns per `tic` group use:

```
stocks_data['log_return'] = df.groupby('tic').prccd.transform(lambda x: np.log(x) - np.log(x.shift(1)))
```

or equivalent formula:

```
stocks_data['log_return'] = df.groupby('tic').prccd.transform(lambda x: np.log(x / x.shift(1)))
```

result:

```
     Date   tic  prccd  log_return
0  1-1-20  AAPL   4.00         NaN
1  2-1-20  AAPL   4.10    0.024693
2  3-1-20  AAPL   4.12    0.004866
3  1-1-20  MSFT   6.00         NaN
4  2-1-20  MSFT   6.15    0.024693
5  3-1-20  MSFT   6.10   -0.008163
```

Comment: Thank you. I just did it with your formula and the results are actually the same